# org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory

Tags: web-services, sockets, ssl, sslsocketfactory

I am trying to connect to SSL web service via Java batch on unix server.

I have setup all certs in my JRE keystore and setup the system property in my code:
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyfile);

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",password);

Now when I am trying to access this webservice by calling it sequenctially for like 50 records, 30 records got successfully processed, but for remaining 20, I got following exception:

Exception:
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory

Not sure why its coming intermittently.

Please help.